# GitHub API - getting an url with Angular's $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github-api

I'm building a small app that ranks github users. I listed of the members I need from the API and I wrote a function that should get an url from all the members. Here is my JS:

```
  var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular'+ '?access_token=MYTOKEN' })
                .then(function(response) {
                $scope.org = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                displayError("Something went wrong");
            });

        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members'+ '?access_token=MYTOKEN' })
                .then(function(response) {
                $scope.members = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                displayError("Something went wrong");
            });

        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=2'+ '&access_token=MYTOKEN' })
                .then(function(response) {
                $scope.members2 = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                displayError("Something went wrong");
            });

        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=3'+'&access_token=MYTOKEN' })
                .then(function(response) {
                $scope.members3 = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                displayError("Something went wrong");
            });
         $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.github.com/users' + '?access_token=MYTOKEN' })
                .then(function(response) {  
                $scope.user = response.data;
                $scope.login = response.data["login"];
                $scope.memberall = $scope.members.concat($scope.members2, $scope.members3);
                   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.memberall.length; i++) {
                   $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.login + '?access_token=MYTOKEN');
                 }
    });
    }]);
```

I can see in the console that it tries to get all of the urls, but I keep getting `"https://api.github.com/users/undefined"` .Does anyone know the reason behind this? What can I do to put the login inside of this url and why "$scope.login" isn't working?

EDIT:
the response.data is a bunch of users, one looks like this:

```
  {
    "login": "mojombo",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
```

---

I need this code:

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users' + '?access_token=21174ee069d6ded5ae3d8ea78d73f15a4cb4890c' })
            .then(function(response) {  
            $scope.user = response.data;
            $scope.memberall = $scope.members.concat($scope.members2, $scope.members3);
                for(var index = 0; index < $scope.memberall.length; index++) {
                   $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.memberall.login + '?access_token=21174ee069d6ded5ae3d8ea78d73f15a4cb4890c');
                 }
            }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
});
```

to find user's login and place them inside urls to GET the url for each angular's organization member. I think I'm close to the answer but I still get "https://api.github.com/users/undefined" in the console.

---

The final working code is:
   $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users' + '?access_token=mytoken' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
            $scope.memberall = $scope.members.concat($scope.members2, $scope.members3);
                for(var index = 0; index < $scope.memberall.length; index++) {
                   $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.memberall[index].login + '?access_token=mytoken');
                 }
            }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
});

Comment: Where is `$scope.login` defined?

Comment: @Quiriacus: Right at the end, before `$scope.memberall`.

Comment: 2 lines above the 'for' loop

Comment: if `response.data` is `$scope.user` then `response.data["login"]` can't be `$scope.login`. How does the structure of data look like?

Comment: what should it be then? '$scope.user.login' ?

Comment: What is stored inside `response.data`. How does the structure look like?

Comment: With the `$scope` variable everything is ok. But there is a mistake by setting them from `response.data`

Comment: i'll post it in my question

Comment: Do you mean an array with a "bunch"? Then you can do something like that: `$scope.login1 = response.data[0].login`

Comment: thanks, but  that gets me the url of the same user 60 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Github's API for [/users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users), `response.data` is an array.

```
var index = 0; // Get 1st user in the array
$scope.login = response.data[index].login;
```

Where `index` is the user's index you want to access.

**Edit**: Since you want to iterate through that array, you could do the following:

```
$scope.users = response.data;
for (var index = 0; index < $scope.users.length; index++) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.users[index].login + "?access_token=MYTOKEN")
    .then(function(data) { 
        // do something on success 
    });
}
```

or

```
$scope.users = response.data;
$scope.users.forEach(element, index) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + element.login + "?access_token=MYTOKEN")
    .then(function(data) { 
        // do something on success 
    });
}
```

**Note** however, according to the API docs, the data that [GET /users/:username](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user) will return, is already contained in the array [GET /users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users) returned. You can loop through the users data you already have - and print their JSON data for example:

```
$scope.users = response.data;
for (var index = 0; index < $scope.users.length; index++) {
    console.log("#" + index + " user: " + $scope.users[index]);
}
```

But it all boils down to what your end goal is.

Comment: almost there, but that gets me the url of the same user 60 times

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through all the users and send a request to [/users/:username](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user) for each?

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I don't need to print the logins though, I already did that, I need them to be placed inside an url to GET the url for each user . I will update my code so you can see what I have now.

Comment: Yea that's the first 2 code snippets you can use under my Edit: label. I was just trying to point out that you already have the data you are trying to fetch.

Comment: I just made a simple change in the code and IT IS WORKING, yeaaaah.

Comment: I'll put the working code in my question if you want to see